# Pandas: How can I remove duplicate rows from DataFrame and calculate their frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a created a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
                    'year':[2000,2001,1998,1999,1998,1998,2000]})
```

That is as follows:

```
    key    year
0    b    2000  
1    b    2001  
2    a    1998  
3    c    1999  
4    a    1998  
5    a    1998  
6    b    2000
```

I want to get the number of occurrences of each line in the fastest possible way:

```
key  year    frequency  
b    2000    2  
b    2001    1  
a    1998    3  
c    1999    1
```

Comment: Did you try to do so?

Comment: I don't know how.Duplicated_drop remove multiple rows but does not count occurrences of the same row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing

```
df1.groupby(['key','year']).size().reset_index()
```

you get...

```
  key  year  0
0   a  1998  3
1   b  2000  2
2   b  2001  1
3   c  1999  1
```

as you see, that column has not been named, so you can do something like

```
mydf = df1.groupby(['key','year']).size().reset_index()
mydf.rename(columns = {0: 'frequency'}, inplace = True)

mydf

  key  year  frequency
0   a  1998          3
1   b  2000          2
2   b  2001          1
3   c  1999          1
```

(you can omit the `.reset_index()` if you want, but in that case you'll need to transform `mydf` into a dataframe, like so: `mydf = pd.DataFrame(mydf)`, and only then rename the column)